# how to show only one woocommerce product from every category?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce

I have multiple categories, like shoes, cloth, Book. So how can I show only one product from each category, means one product of shoes, one product of Book and one product of Cloth should be display.
Please help me how can I do that.

Thanks & Regards,
Dharmendra,

Answer (score 0):

**So simple.**

You can do this by using widget like woocommerce featured products, just select products from each category and call this widget.

Comment: Thanx Balram for your response, actually I have to show only 10 products within front slider, so I have done that but I want to show only one product from each category.